# Django window function with aggregation function on the same annotate

Tags: python, django, orm, backend

I am trying to use Django aggregation function SUM in an `annotate` along with Django window functions. The problem is that when I try to use the aggregation function on the same model field as used in previous annotate alias, then Django throws `window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY` error. I am providing the query below.

```
queryset = UserEcosystemApplicationUsage.objects.filter(
    user_app__user=child,
    from_datetime__gte=from_datetime,
    to_datetime__lte=to_datetime
).annotate(
    day_duration_seconds=Epoch(Window(
       expression=Sum('duration_time'),
          partition_by=[F('name'), F('date')]
       )),
    period_duration_seconds=Epoch(Window(
       expression=Sum('duration_time'),
          partition_by=[F('name')],
       )),
    # duration_total_seconds=Epoch(Window(
    #     expression=Sum('duration_time')
    # )),
    duration_total_seconds=Sum('duration_time')
).values(
    'duration_total_seconds'
).distinct()
```

Right now, when commented out part of query is used instead of `Sum(duration_time)` then everything is OK but I would expect to `Sum('duration_time')` to work as well. Could you pinpoint what I am doing wrong or present links to docs that explains what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was because the Pagination used the aggregation `count` on the queryset. You may need to remove/change aggregations done on the queryset downstream in your code.